# How to write csv file using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am creating one array dynamically.Following array is one example.

```
textarray = [["label first","details of label 1"],["label sec","details of label 2"],["label 3","details of label 3"],["label 4","details of label 4 and 3"],["label 5","details of label 5"],["label 6","details of label 6"],["label 7","details of label 7"],["label 8","details of label 8"],["label 9","details of label 9"]]
```

My ultimate goal is onclick on save button array will be generated and it should ask me for save/open in **EXCEL format**. So i have written something like this,

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href     = 'data:attachment/csv;charset=utf-8,' +textarray;
a.target   = '_blank';
a.download = 'myFile.csv';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

I am getting prompt to save or open csv file but if i open that file, contents are not as expected(not showing properly)

It is coming like this,

```
            **column1**   **column2**   ...........
**row1**    labelfirst  detailsoflabel1  labelsec  detailsoflabel2
```

One row should contain only one element and if you see the above output there is no space in between words(see the array). It should be like this,

```
               **column1**       **column2**

 **row1**      label first    details of label 1

 **row2**      label sec      details of label 2

    .
    .
    .
```

Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript code to parse CSV data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data)

Comment: No its not helpful because i am not interested in parsing csv data. Here i am creating csv.

Comment: @user3136030 -- I think the main problem here is that you're not escaping/quoting anything or adding any newlines between rows.

Comment: @mgilson yes you are right.But i am confused with array formatting.

Comment: You're right.  My bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Use this:**
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function createCSV() {  
csvRows = [["label first","details of label 1"],["label sec","details of label 2"],["label 3","details of label 3"],["label 4","details of label 4 and 3"],["label 5","details of label 5"],["label 6","details of label 6"],["label 7","details of label 7"],["label 8","details of label 8"],["label 9","details of label 9"]];

    var csvString = csvRows.join("%0A");
    var a         = document.createElement('a');
    a.href        = 'data:attachment/csv,' + csvString;
    a.target      = '_blank';
    a.download    = 'myFile.csv';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();

}
</script>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="button" value="Create" onclick="createCSV()">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```